# Hello, in this code I need to find exact place of letters, my code finds only place of one letter, but I want to find the place of 2 or more letters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

```
const f = (newStr, givenWord) => {
  let arr = [...newStr];
  let newArr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i + Math.sqrt(arr.length) < arr.length + 1; i += Math.sqrt(arr.length)) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + Math.sqrt(arr.length)))
  }

  console.log(newArr);

  for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < newArr[i].length; j++) {
      if (newArr[i][j] == givenWord) {
        return [i, j];
      }
    }
  }
  return [-1, -1];
};

let result = f("QWEASDZXC", "A");
console.log(`[${result[0]} ${result[1]}]`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with this approach

```
(function(word, letters) {
    // Convert letters words in an array with indexes of each letter in the word
    const indexes = letters.split('').map(letter => word.indexOf(letter));
    return indexes.filter(index => index !== -1);
})('QWEASDZXC', 'AC');
```

Input

```
'QWEASDZXC' 
'AC'
```

Output received

```
[ 3, 8 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, "QLGNAEKIRLRNGEAE", "KING"
Expected result: [1, 2] -> [1, 3] -> [0, 3] -> [0, 2].
I need this output

Comment: @HokmiranSoltanli it's totally unclear how that input should lead to the "expected output" in your comment, can you please expand your question to explain what you're looking for?

Comment: myarray=[ ['Q', 'W', 'E']
 ['A', 'S', 'D']
 ['Z', 'X', 'C']] this is my array like 3x3 matrix. When I search the place of "W" it shows as output [0,1]. But when I search for example "WSD" it returns [-1.-1] in my code, but answer must be [0,1]->[1,1]->[1,2]